# How to add an integer to certain elements in a list?

Tags: python, list, integer

I am using python3,

I want to add 50 to second and third elements in the list below.

```
list_ = [0,0,0,0,0]

desiredlist = [0,50,50,0,0]
```

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ignore the down votes, for new users folks should constructively explain why they are down voting. There are several answers given below - if one has answered your question, please mark it as such. If not, please clarify your question so that you can get the help you need.

Comment: I won't suggest to ignore the downvotes (like @SteveJ wrote), but don't take them personally either. They are feedback on your post, not on you as a person. Learn from the feedback, and if you don't understand what you're doing wrong, please take the [tour] and browse a bit through the [help] section, especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To learn Python, please consider following a tutorial to learn at least the basics. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
add_to_elements = [1, 2]

for i in range(len(list_)):
    if i in add_to_elements:
        list_[i] += 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with doing this?

```
list[1] += 50
list[2] += 50
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index value then you can use insert function

insert takes argument as index and value EX: insert(index,value)

```
list_ = [0,0,0,0,0]
list_.insert(1,50)
list_.insert(2,50)
```

Answer (score 0):

type the index you want to change and assign the new value:

```
list_[1] = 50

list_[2] = 50
```

note: top of list starts with zero